# Synchronising timer in server in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I am trying to find a way to write a timerfunction that automatically calls a function after certain time interval. Currently, my timer is done at the client side and I am using the setinterval() function but then lets say many users are accessing my dashboard and I dont want too many DB calls, so I want to synchronise the timer in server end in node. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: `Javascript` is generally not multi-threaded .

Comment: Why u just don't use `setInterval()` on node server? it's available there also https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args

Answer (score 0):

setInterval() will do your work when implemented on your server side JS controller code.

Comment: I have written an ajax function which is passed to the setinterval on the client side. Now, if I use the setinterval on the server side, how do I call the ajax function repeatedly after every few minutes?

Comment: @jessica you can call `ajax` method with `setInterval()` like the way, `function foo{ $.ajax({ your ajax method here details})}` `setInterval(foo,8000);`// called after 8sec